# Error with simple UILabel?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

I have a little problem:

I have a view with a view controller and a tabbarcontroller in a main window.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:     (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
// Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window

self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

On this view I have around 10 Labels.

As soon as I connect 1 Label on the Interface-Builder with the UILabel in the controller, I get a `SIGBART` error.

Here is my code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SelfViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *id2;
    IBOutlet UILabel *username;
    IBOutlet UILabel *vorname;
    IBOutlet UILabel *nachname;
    IBOutlet UILabel *email;
}

@end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As soon as you connect 1 label from the background to the view?  What does that mean?  What code are you using to do this?  We'll need more specifics...

Comment: also you should declare simply UILabels in the interface, then declare the IBOutlet UILabels in properties below the interface

Comment: This sentence itself is really confusing, as well: "I have a view with a view controller and a tabbarcontroller in a main window."  The `UITabBarController` is your `window`'s `rootViewController`, I assume?  And we're talking about the view controller for one of the `UITabBarController`'s tabs?

Comment: Edited all things, hope you can understand it now!

Comment: Can you post the crash log? What is the exception? Most probably you have something connected wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, very basic and simple but very frustrating too:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1598422?threadID=1598422